# RPi4 Bullseye Access Point and Client Simultaneously

Tags: access-point

Can a Raspberry Pi be, simultaneously:

1. a client connected to a 3rd party Wi-Fi access point, and
2. an access point that other computers can connect to and be assigned an IP address (so that they can SSH into the Pi without being connected to the 3rd party Wi-Fi network)?

To be clear, there's no need for the computer connecting to the Pi to have access to the internet via the 3rd party access point. My use case is literally so that a computer can open a web page hosted by the Pi, not to use the Pi as a full-service Access Point. I just would rather that my Pi not have to lose access to the internet just to be an AP.

It would also be great if I could turn the Access Point functionality on and off by running a script on the Pi, and tell whether the Access Point is currently on by running another script on the Pi.

Comment: I believe it is possible, but I have never tried. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/119668/8697 for one example. Personally I would use an additional WiFi adapter.